# How to randomly active and non activate buttons when enter key is pressed and one more issue?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
let element = document.querySelector('.textarea');
let cont = document.querySelector('.groupofbtns');
let lastlen = 0;
element.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        let grp = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')
        let l = grp.length - 1, arr = [];
        console.log(grp.length)
        do {
            let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * l + 1);
            arr.push(num);
            arr = arr.filter((item, index) => {
                return arr.indexOf(item) === index
            });
        } while (arr.length < l);
        console.log(arr);
        for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log(`in the toggling loop ${i}`)
                grp[arr[i]].classList.remove("active");
                grp[arr[i]].classList.add("active");
            }, 10000)
        }
    }
    else if (event.keyCode === 8) {
        let val = element.value;
        //console.log(val)
        let strArr = val.split(',')
        let b, f;
        let grp = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
        if (strArr.length > 1) {
            b = strArr;
            while (b[b.length - 1] == "")
                b.pop()
            if (b.length < strArr.length) {
                cont.removeChild(grp[grp.length - 1]);
                lastlen--;
            }
            f = b[b.length - 1];
        }
        if (grp.length == b.length)
            grp[grp.length - 1].innerText = `${f}`;
        else {
            let diff = grp.length - b.length
            let i = 0;
            while (diff > 0) {
                cont.removeChild(grp[grp.length - 1 - i]);
                i++;
                diff--;
                lastlen--;
            }
        }
    }
});
element.addEventListener('input', function (event) {
    let val = element.value;
    //console.log(val)
    let strArr = val.split(',')
    let b, f;
    if (strArr.length > 1) {
        b = strArr;
        while (b[b.length - 1] == "")
            b.pop()
        f = b[b.length - 1];

        if (event.keyCode !== 8) {
            if (strArr.length > lastlen) {
                let butt = document.createElement('button');
                butt.classList.add('btn')
                butt.classList.add('btn-warning')
                //butt.classList.add('container')
                butt.classList.add('active')
                butt.innerText = `${f}`
                cont.appendChild(butt)
                lastlen = strArr.length
                //cont.innerHTML += `<button type="button" class="btns" >${f}</button>`;
            }//element.value = val;
            else {

                let b = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')
                b[b.length - 1].innerText = `${f}`
            }
        }
    }
})
```

```css
.h
{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 50%;
    margin-top:30%;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
.lab
{
    color:white;
   
}
.btn
{
    margin: 0.8% 0.8%;
}
.groupofbtns
{
    width:50%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Random color picker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="randomcolorcss.css">
</head>

<body style="background-color: blue;">
    <div class="container h">
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="text" class="lab">Enter your choices here separate them with
                commas, Press
                Enter when you are
                done</label>
            <br>
            <textarea cols="5" rows="5" class=" textarea form-control" placeholder="Enter Choices here" name="text"
                style="width: fit-content; display: block;"></textarea>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="groupofbtns container">
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="randomcolor.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am a beginner is javascript , I am trying to make a basic web page in which as user type inside the text box...let's say a and then put a comma(,) then one button gets created and likewise more the length of the text and as we type comma the button will be created ...after that when the user clicks on the enter button ..all the present button color brightness should go to low and high randomly with some time lag..just like when decoration lights... but I am not getting how to do it... I tried to generate the permutations from 1 to Number-of-present-buttons then tried to toggle the active class but it's not working...with the help of set timeout......

2nd Issue is
When I press backspace just before the button gets deleted the last button for a fraction of second shows the value of just neighboring buttons ...How to resolve this issue?

Please help me with this

Comment: @Temani Was there any problem with previous heading

Comment: no need to add JS in the title, we have tags for this